# How to build Rewrite rules to a expecific condition

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, vhosts, url-rewrite-module

we want a subdomain to the register form.

The project is a Code Igniter website.

Our idea is to use register.domain.com

I'm trying to build a rewrite rules to make this.

```
If the domain is 
    register.domain.com/whatever 
go to 
    register.domain.com/register/form
if the domain is 
    register.domain.com/register/form
do nothing.
```

Now I only get a infinity looping.

thanks

Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i hope it is what you need

With RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)/ http://new.example.com/docs/$1
```

EDIT:

I saw you need a condition so:

```
 <If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/register/login'">
  RedirectMatch ^/(.*)/ http://new.example.com/docs/$1
 </If>
```

FINALLY:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+

RewriteRule  ^(.*)/ /register/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the easy way.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^register.domain.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^register.domain.com/register/form [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://register.domain.com/register/form r [L,R=301]
```

The ! is "ISNOT" :)